# How to use sisense custom plugins

Tags: sisense

I've downloaded and installed `Sisense V 8.0.1.10112` on my local machine. I wanted to learn the Plugin mechanism of Sisense. I downloaded `HelloWorldWidget`from the list and extracted the contents to `C:\Program Files\Sisense\app\plugins\HelloWorldWidget` as mentioned in the documentation. But I'm not sure from where this plugin will show up. Am I looking at the wrong place i.e Add new widget window. I even restarted the entire software. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"In the Sisense Admin page, you can view a list of your current plug-ins, their version as defined in your plug-in’s script, and their status, enabled or disabled."

[image]

Source: https://documentation.sisense.com/latest/administration/manage-plugin.htm#gsc.tab=0